# g++ warning on old-style-cast (C casts) with a legacy C header having macros

Tags: c++, casting, g++, compiler-warnings

I want g++ `-Wold-style-cast` to warn me about C-style casts in my C++ code. 
The problem is a C API with macros that look like functions.

I can use `#pragma` to disable the warning for the include (see example). This works for inline functions, but not for macro expansion.

**How can I quiet C-style warnings when using the C API macros, but enable them for my c++ code?**

Example

```cpp
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wold-style-cast"
#include "example_c_api.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop  // Removing the `pop` quiets **all** warnings

float my_cpp_code()
{
    int i= func_inline(42.f); // no warning here == good
    int j = funcy_macro(1); // don't want a warning here -- just using the C API.
    return (float)i + (float)j; // I WANT a warning here.
}
```

with the C API header

```c
/* example_c_api.h  : a C API header that naturally uses C-style casts */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 

#define funcy_macro(x)  (int)x 

inline int func_inline(float f) { return (int)f; }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

With g++ versions 4.8.5, 5.4.0, and 7.3.0 I get two warnings instead of the one I want...

```
$ g++ -Wold-style-cast -c wosc.cc 
wosc.cc: In function ‘float my_cpp_code()’:
wosc.cc:9:25: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
     int j = funcy_macro(1); // don't want a warning here -- just using the C API.
                         ^
example_c_api.h:6:30: note: in definition of macro ‘funcy_macro’
 #define funcy_macro(x)  (int)x 
                              ^
wosc.cc:10:19: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
     return (float)i + (float)j; // I WANT a warning here.
```

There are a couple of solutions that are too ugly and/or time-consuming to do.

- Turning the warning off/on for each macro call
- Writing individual wrapper inline functions

Comment: "Turning the warning off/on for each macro call" - *Or* put the turning off/on *into the macro itself*.

Comment: Run with `-Wold-style-cast` separately, like in a nightly QA build, and filter out false positives.